# How do you refresh the ribbons in all open windows

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing a VSTO Outlook 2013 add-in and created an Explorer XML ribbon file to display some custom ribbon buttons. The addin runs a long running async process when a ribbon button is clicked and I display a "Loading details..." label in the Explorer ribbon to inform the user what's happening and to allow them to continue working in Outlook.

When the long running process finishes it calls the following code to refresh the ribbon and hide the loading label:

```
RibbonUI.Invalidate();
```

The problem is, if the user has 2 Explorer windows open, only the ribbon in the active window is refreshed (and the other explorer window(s) remain displaying the Loading label).

I've tried looping round the open explorer windows and activating each one to try and force the Ribbon to refresh, but it didn't work.

Can someone please tell me how I can force the ribbons in all the open windows in Outlook to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

How many times was the [IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonextensibility.getcustomui.aspx) callback invoked?

Typically your Ribbon callbacks should be invoked when you move focus to another Outlook window.

Comment: The GetCustomUI callback is invoked once for "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer" with 2 explorer windows open. So how can I force the ribbons in both Explorer windows to refresh?

Comment: You do that in the right way. Both explorer windows should update their state. Will try to reproduce the issue a bit later.

Comment: RibbonUI must be cached when the onLoad callback is executed. Is that where you cache the RibbonUI object?

Comment: I think the IRibbonUI instance is cached properly due to the fact that the active explorer window is updated correctly.